# Background image sometimes disappears when loading a png image over it

Tags: css, google-chrome

This is the website: http://www.bilocali.it/vendita/lazio/

The problem is regarding the Map on the left side with google chrome only. 
Till June everything was working properly.

The map has a background image that sometimes disappear when I rollover and load a png over it with a simple function like this:

```
function rollover_region() {$('#region_div').attr('src',"/images/region/image.png");}
```

Sometimes when I do a refresh  it works. I really can't understand.
On all other browser everything is fine. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Clear your cache and check.

Comment: I Already tried It, that didn't fix it...

Comment: You have an Js issue:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alpha' of undefined on index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a js issue on your map.

To correct your roll over map problem, you can correct the js issue:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alpha' of undefined on index
```

Or, you can add this quick css trick:

**CSS**

```
.regione_attiva img {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

You'r welcome =)

Comment: Well spotted =)
Thanks